# How to hide user from login screen using .NET C#?

Tags: c#, .net, group-policy

I need to **hide** a user account name from "Switch User" screen on Windows. For that I need to add that user's name into 
Local Computer Policy / Computer configuration / Windows Settings / Security Settings / Local Policies / User Rights Assignment / "Deny log on locally".

**I need to do that programmatically.**

**Do you know how to do that in .NET C#?**

Any link or any hint might be helpful...

Thanks.

Comment: I guess these settings must be accessible with WMI (using the `System.Management` classes).

Comment: @ManuLetroll Thanks for ideas. do you have any examples, or helpfull links how to do that?

Comment: [This tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) may help you generate the required code. Unfortunately I've very little experience with WMI, I don't know exactly where you have to set that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write information in registry

at first read this [Configuring User Rights](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277404.aspx) (you can find the same for other OS)

at second read this [Read-write-and-delete-from-registry](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C)

**EDIT**

For Win7 and Vista [Win7 and Vista](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-switch-user-option-in-windows-vista-and-7/)

**EDIT2**

Go to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" and create a new key called "SpecialAccounts". Create a subkey of "SpecialAccounts" called "UserList". In the "UserList" key, create a DWORD value with the name of the account you want to hide, and leave the value of that DWORD set to 0. Do this for every account you want to hide.

all of this you can do with [second link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C)

Comment: Thanks for response. But I need to hide only particular account name, not to disable Switch User option.

Comment: @User1234 if you need something more, then ask